# How to make nusoap server with nusoap lib, and call using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, soap-client, nusoap

I make nusoap server.php file with nusoap-0.9.5 php in my localhost,
now in index.html file, how  can I call "getmessage" function using the javascript, such as:

Below code not working.. please help..

```html
    <?php //---server.php--begin---(php) 
    require_once("lib/nusoap.php"); //liberary
    $server = new nusoap_server(); 
    $server->configureWSDL("myService","urn:service1"); // configuare WSDL
    function getmessage($message){
        return "Welcome ".$message;
    }
    $server->register(
        "getmessage",
        array("name"=>"xsd:string"), //input
        array("sum"=>"xsd:string") //output
    );
    //http listener
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    //---server.php--end---
   ?>
```

-------------------Javascript SOAP Client--------------------

```
        <!---index.html--begin---(javascript html)--->
        <SCRIPT language='javascript' src='soapclient.js'></SCRIPT>
        <SCRIPT>
            var url = "http://localhost/server.php?wsdl";
            function getmessage()
            {
                var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
                pl.add("name", document.frmDemo.txtName.value);
                SOAPClient.invoke(url, "getmessage", pl, true, getmessage_callBack);
            }
            function getmessage_callBack(r)
            {
                alert(r);
            }

     </SCRIPT>
    <form id="frmDemo" name="frmDemo" action="" method="post">
        <input name="txtName" id="txtName" value="Matteo" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="click here" name="button"  onClick="getmessage();"> <br>
    </form>

      <!---index.html--end--->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript don't have stable library for soap, you must make it or use customized simple lib by any developers.. for example go to this link and do it:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-wsajax/